# jQuery removeclass doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css

```
$('.shortcode').removeClass('.shortcode');
$('.shortcode').hide();
```

Why `.shortcode` items gets hidden anyway? In source code they still have shortcode class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove the dot '.'. This will work

```
$('.shortcode').removeClass('shortCode');
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! The freaking dot, I just killed an hour on this :)

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't use `.` in the string passed to `removeClass`: this...

```
$('.shortcode').removeClass('shortCode');
```

... is sufficient. Think of it: if method is intended to remove a *class* anyway, why should you mark its argument with the class sigil (`.`)? :)

With dot in front of the real className, jQuery tries to remove `'.shortCode'` class - obviously, it's a no-op here.